# WPF Rectangle does not have a Click event

Tags: wpf, events, shapes

It seems that the WPF [Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx) shape does not have the Click event defined. What am I supposed to use instead?

It does have MouseUp, but it's not quite the same behavior.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you're not happy with `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`, perhaps you could just put the `Rectangle` in a `Button` and handle the `Button`'s `Click` event?

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle .../>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

It really depends with the behavior you're after. Please elaborate if needs be.

Comment: This is probably what I want.

Answer (score 28):

To add click handing to a Rectangle itself, you can use the [InputBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black">
    <Rectangle.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding FooCommand}"/>
    </Rectangle.InputBindings>
</Rectangle>
```

This will cause the FooCommand to be executed when the rectangle is clicked. Handy if you're using MVVM!

Comment: It's available in .NET 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: This answer does not work in .NET 3.5, only in .NET 4 and later. In .NET 3.5 the Command property is not registered as a dependency property, so it cannot be set to a binding. See my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427638/if-we-cant-bind-a-mousebindings-command-what-are-we-supposed-to-do

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the related DoubleClick event and came across [this suggestion](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2011/08/03/wpf-tip-using-a-mousedoubleclick-event-where-none-exists.aspx) to simply embed the object of interest in a ContentControl.

Here is their example (with a border, which also did not support click/double click).

```
<ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="OnDoubleClick">
    <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid Margin="4">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" />
            <TextBlock Text="Hello" FontSize="15" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score -1):

Rectangle has event [Tapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.tapped), which works fine. In designing universal apps for Windows 8.1, there are new events. Tapped, DoubleTaped, RightTapped and Holding.