# If we can't bind a MouseBinding's Command, what are we supposed to do?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, inputbinding

I would love to be able to use a regular `MouseBinding` to capture a CTRL-Click event on my `TextBlock`. Unfortunately the `Command` property is not a dependency property and I'm using MVVM, so I can't bind it to my viewmodel.

How could Microsoft have left out this basic functionality? Are there no easy ways to detect CTRL-Clicks and bind them to a command in my viewmodel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always take a look at using [Attached Command Behaviours](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/).

Answer (score 6):

Originally I believe I was referring to the use of `TextBlock`'s `InputBindings` member.

**In .NET 4 `InputsBinding`s now inherit from `Freezable`, so now the `Command` property is dependency property** (see [Binding support in InputBindings](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/10/26/vs2010-binding-support-in-inputbindings/)), **solving the binding issue.**

If you are stuck with .NET 3.5 you could create some attached properties for any type of event that you want. In your `OnCommandChanged` function add the event handler, and filter based on modifiers (like the `Control` key or the `ClickCount`) in your `PropertyChangedCallback` method.

Comment: Link is broken.