# Connecting mouse events with ViewModel via MouseBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command, icommand

I have a user control having some `telerik` controls in it. I have a coded a ViewModel where all the business logic resides.

I need to intercept the `LeftClick` event to know when a user clicks on the `telerik` control. I tried using the `MouseBinding` technique to bind the `LeftClick` to the event handler in the ViewModel.

I am not sure about what the signature is for the event handler. I read somewhere that the command to bind should be of type `ICommand` and the execute method takes only one parameter.

The signature for the `LeftClick` event is:

```cs
public void SelectItem(object o, EventArgs e)
```

How can I pass the extra argument to the execute method?

I have written the following XAML:

```xml
<telerik:RadTransitionControl.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="SelectedItem" />
</telerik:RadTransitionControl.InputBindings>
```

How should I define `SelectedItem` in the ViewModel?

Will `Command="SelectedItem"` work? Or should I add a binding clause here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If we can't bind a MouseBinding's Command, what are we supposed to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427638/if-we-cant-bind-a-mousebindings-command-what-are-we-supposed-to-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the MouseBinding's Command property is not a DependencyProperty, so you cannot bind something to it.

See here for a similar problem:

[If we can't bind a MouseBinding's Command, what are we supposed to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427638/if-we-cant-bind-a-mousebindings-command-what-are-we-supposed-to-do)

Basically, per the accepted answer to that question, you'll have to use the AttachedCommandBehavior rather than a MouseBinding to achieve what you want. In my opinion that would be the best way if this is something you do a lot.

Alternatively, if this is the only case in your code that you are doing this I don't think it would hurt to handle the event in code behind and call the view model's command from there. MVVM purists might disagree, but sometimes it's best to do things the simple way rather than tying yourself in knots trying to keep your code behind completely empty!

Comment: According to another answer on the question you are linking to, the command is now a DependencyProperty in **.NET 4**.

Comment: Yeah it is now a DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 4):

First thing you need some kind of [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) which implement System.Windows.Input.ICommand. This will help you on Binding.

XAML

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand}" />
```

ViewModel

```
class YourViewModel
{
   public void SelectItem(object o)
   {       }

   private ICommand selectedItemCommand
   public ICommand SelectedItemCommand 
   {
     get
     {
        if(selectedItemCommand == null)
        { 
          // RelayCommand will point to SelectItem() once mouse is clicked
          selectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectItem);
        }

        return selectedItemCommand;
     } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Command value should be a binding, not just a property name:

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding SelectedItem}" CommandParameter="..." />
```

Then whatever you pass into CommandParameter will be the extra argument which is passed to Execute.

Comment: i am getting an error "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Command' property of type 'MouseBinding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

Comment: Ah, apologies. I thought you already had a command set up in the View Model. You'll need to set up the DelegateCommand class, as described here: http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html and then bind to a command called SelectedItemCommand which would be of type DelegateCommand.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the ICommand derived class and exception is thrown when i bind an object of that class to MouseBinding

Comment: Ah OK, I misread your error message. See my alternative answer to this question then.